# ruby on rails graphql test file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I'm learning Ruby on Rails with graphQL and following this tutorial

https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/3-mutations/

I'm at the last part with the unit test and I just don't know where to create the `create_link_test.rb` file. The file path in the tutorial doesn't make sense to me, idk where to find the `graphql-ruby` directory within my project. I tried running `rails test` on git bash but it returns this which I think means it didn't run the test file:

[image]

I appreciate any help! Edit: I created my file in `app/graphql/mutations` to try running `rails test`

Comment: "graphql-ruby" is what they named the rails app. To create your test file where they specified, you'll need to create subfolders under `test`. then place your new test file under `test/graphql/mutations/create_link_test.rb`. Any file under the "test" directory that ends in `_test.rb` should get run automatically with `rails test`, but you may need to use `bundle exec rails test` or `bin/rails test` to get the right bundler environment loaded.

Comment: that was a silly mistake on my part for naming my project something else, thanks for the help!